# How to copy a lof or small size files in one folder by one go ?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, move, tar

How to change your implementations if you have to move a lot of small-size text files in the same directory by one go ?

I think "mv" or "tar" can do this.

Are there some better ways ? faster or reliable ?

Thanks

Comment: More details please.  Are you trying to move them over the network?  Over a USB or Firewire link to an external drive?  Between directories on the same hard drive?  How much data are we talking about? (MB, GB, etc.)

Comment: Also you have several tags, are you doing this in C++, or just want suggestions on approaches, even if they're not something you write a program to do?

Comment: Can you try putting more effort into the question?  As it stands it is quite unclear what your asking.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have 100,000 small text files (each one is < 5k). I need to move them to another folder in the same disk drive and also to another disk drive of another remote host. Also, assure that no damage or errors to these files.

Comment: in the future, when answering questions clarifying your question please edit your question, marking the change like **edit** and make a note in comments to indicate thqt you are answering the comments/questions in the main body of your posting. Good luck.

Comment: If all 100K are under a single folder and you want to move them (not copy), `mv` will take care of it pretty easily (and all it does is change the underlying reference in the file system to that folder). If you're copying them to a remote server, `tar`ing them and copying them over is fast. If you want validity, you can generate a checksum of the tarfile with something like `sha1sum` or `md5sum`, and check that it's the same on your system as the remote. If you want per-file verification, you can use `rsync`, which will be slower up front (but fast for future syncing).

Answer (score 1):

[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is a widely popular tool for moving files.  It's hard to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move files in linux use this code in the command line:

`mv /original/path/* /destination/`

If you need to do this from a C++ program use:

`system(mv /original/path/* /destination/);`